# How do I remove these radiators from the wall?

Tags: radiator

[image: Side 1]
[image: Side 2]
[image: Top/ Side 2]

As per the title really.

How do I release these sprung radiator holders/ clips so I can access behind the radiator?
Link below as the Pictures are too big.

https://tinyurl.com/bdhhp782

Comment: A link to Google Drive (obfuscated at that) is problematic for many of us; could you please upload the images here instead?

Comment: Looks like that bracket is "painted" to the wall. My thought is that bracket is spring loaded but it probably wont move till you break the paint bond. Did you try pulling the bracket up, does it move at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push on the spring loaded bracket on the left side.

Then pull it up.

[image: spring]

Comment: Conceptually this answers the question - I will ad to actaully make it work with the restricted space I eneded up using a long screwdriver and hammer to push the upper retainer on the other side up and back as far as possible, then the lower retainer and repeat until the clip was pushed through enough for the spring to pull it fully out.